# Java: filter to a servlet failed to work properly

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, servlet-filters

I am trying to add a filter to a servlet:
The `filter` configuration is like this:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "AFilter",urlPatterns = "/*", servletNames = "AServlet")

  public class AFilter implements Filter {
         public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("filter is dying");
}
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    System.out.println("filter is working");
}
  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("filter is born");
}
```

and my `AServlet` is like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AServlet",urlPatterns = "/AServlet")

public class AServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("AServlet");
}
```

}

I am using annotation to configure the mapping of the servlet and filter, so the `web.xml`file is empty, however the problem is when I try to run the web application I got this output:

```
AFilter is born
AFilter is working
AFilter is working
AFilter is working
```

It seems some programs has invoke the `AFilter` 3 times and I failed to figure out which, and also when I tried to access the `Aservlet` from the web browser:`http://localhost:80/AServlet`, I see the console is like this:

```
AServlet
AFilter is working
```

This is really confusing that it seems I visited `AServlet` successfully and `AFilter` is doing its job as well. So can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance. (BTW: the IDE I am using is Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition)

Comment: I have figured out the reason why the filter `doFilter`method invoked 3 times as when the web application starts, the `index.jsp` (which is under the urlpattern="/*")is the default landing page, so I change my urlpattern=`/web/service/` and the filter is work line is gone, but when I access `AServlet`, the problem I mentioned above is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved after I read some filter-servlet articles on the Internet, the problem is the line:`chain.doFilter(req,resp)`, I should delete this line of code, otherwise filter will send request and response to the destination I visit anyway.

Comment: Although this question is already answered.... I got confused when u said u should delete chain.dofilter(). If u delete it, then how  the request be forwarded to the appropriate resources?

Comment: oh this is just a test case, I just want to see if my filter is working or not